# What is the difference between linux command "screen" and "&" when you want to run a background task?

Tags: linux, shell, background-process

Curious.

Sometimes I want to run the Django Server for a long time. Stackflow give

1. Screen

   ```
   [user@host]$screen

   [user@host]$python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

   [user@host]$screen -d
   ```
2. &

   ```
   python manage.py runserver &
   ```

Both works fine. What is the difference?

Comment: screen is a terminal multiplexer http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ and adding & to any execution basically daemonizes process AFAIK.

Comment: @sagarchalise: Not quite. From the manual: *If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way how it works is completely different.

`screen` provides a virtual terminal which is kept and can be attached to, even from several points at once.

`&`, OTOH, just creates the process in the background. If you quit the shell, the process loses its stdin, stdout, stderr. On any subsequent output, it gets a `SIGPIPE` and exits.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. If I want some process running all the time, which way should I use? Thanks

Comment: If you want to run the script all the time you can use the Screen command